# Ubuntu 18.04 X forwarding to MobaXterm is broken

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xorg, intellij, x11-forwarding

When launching IntelliJ IDEA locally on Ubuntu 18.04 laptop it works well. However, when launching it from a Windows 10 machine in the same network via X forwarding of MobaXterm, it produces the following errors:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
2019-12-25 12:43:12,218 [  19129]   WARN - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - UI freezed for 5050ms, details saved to /home/serge/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/system/log/threadDumps-freeze-20191225-124307-IU-193.5662.53-Unsafe.park-5sec
2019-12-25 12:43:13,009 [  19920]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1483)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1704)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1330)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getRule(StyleSheet.java:281)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1483)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1562)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1318)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getRule(StyleSheet.java:255)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet$ViewAttributeSet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:2745)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getViewAttributes(StyleSheet.java:362)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.setPropertiesFromAttributes(BlockView.java:404)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.setParent(BlockView.java:74)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.CompositeView.replace(CompositeView.java:219)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.BoxView.replace(BoxView.java:182)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.CompositeView.loadChildren(CompositeView.java:114)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.CompositeView.setParent(CompositeView.java:139)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.setParent(BlockView.java:72)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML$Renderer.<init>(BasicHTML.java:411)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.createHTMLView(BasicHTML.java:84)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.updateRenderer(BasicHTML.java:231)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.propertyChange(BasicLabelUI.java:482)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:341)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:333)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8747)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:324)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip$Header.<init>(HelpTooltip.java:529)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip$Header.<init>(HelpTooltip.java:513)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip.createTipPanel(HelpTooltip.java:325)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip.initPopupBuilder(HelpTooltip.java:289)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip.installOn(HelpTooltip.java:257)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.updateToolTipText(ActionButton.java:362)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.addNotify(ActionButton.java:250)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1146)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:436)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.fillToolBar(ActionToolbarImpl.java:319)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.actionsUpdated(ActionToolbarImpl.java:1115)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.updateActionsImpl(ActionToolbarImpl.java:1098)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.access$000(ActionToolbarImpl.java:53)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl$1.updateActionsImpl(ActionToolbarImpl.java:166)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ToolbarUpdater$MyUpdateRunnable.run(ToolbarUpdater.java:172)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ToolbarUpdater.updateActions(ToolbarUpdater.java:87)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ToolbarUpdater.updateActions(ToolbarUpdater.java:79)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.updateActionsImmediately(ActionToolbarImpl.java:1080)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.addNotify(ActionToolbarImpl.java:206)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1146)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:436)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.installNorthComponents(IdeRootPane.java:325)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ProjectFrameHelper.setProject(ProjectFrameHelper.java:419)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.WindowManagerImpl.assignFrame(WindowManagerImpl.java:518)
        at com.intellij.platform.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$projectLoaded$1.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:176)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:309)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:687)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:965)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:186)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:172)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:455)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:453)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:82)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:250)
        at com.intellij.platform.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$1.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:64)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:149)
        at com.intellij.platform.ProjectUiFrameAllocator.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.openExistingProject(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:234)
        at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase.openProject(RecentProjectsManagerBase.kt:281)
        at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase.reopenLastProjectsOnStart(RecentProjectsManagerBase.kt:382)
        at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter$main$4.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:533)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:107)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:116)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
        at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter.main(ApplicationLoader.kt:523)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$8$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:242)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:193)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$8.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:241)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:783)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2019-12-25 12:43:13,012 [  19923]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1  Build #IU-193.5662.53
2019-12-25 12:43:13,012 [  19923]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - JDK: 11.0.5; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2019-12-25 12:43:13,012 [  19923]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - OS: Linux
2019-12-25 12:43:13,054 [  19965]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Last Action:
2019-12-25 12:43:13,161 [  20072]  ERROR - .impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1483)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1704)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1330)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getRule(StyleSheet.java:281)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1483)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.createResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1562)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getResolvedStyle(StyleSheet.java:1318)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getRule(StyleSheet.java:255)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet$ViewAttributeSet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:2745)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.getViewAttributes(StyleSheet.java:362)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.setPropertiesFromAttributes(BlockView.java:404)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.setParent(BlockView.java:74)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.CompositeView.replace(CompositeView.java:219)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.BoxView.replace(BoxView.java:182)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.CompositeView.loadChildren(CompositeView.java:114)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.CompositeView.setParent(CompositeView.java:139)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.setParent(BlockView.java:72)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML$Renderer.<init>(BasicHTML.java:411)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.createHTMLView(BasicHTML.java:84)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.updateRenderer(BasicHTML.java:231)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.propertyChange(BasicLabelUI.java:482)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:341)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:333)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8747)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:324)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip$Header.<init>(HelpTooltip.java:529)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip$Header.<init>(HelpTooltip.java:513)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip.createTipPanel(HelpTooltip.java:325)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip.initPopupBuilder(HelpTooltip.java:289)
        at com.intellij.ide.HelpTooltip.installOn(HelpTooltip.java:257)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.updateToolTipText(ActionButton.java:362)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.addNotify(ActionButton.java:250)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.addNotify(ActionToolbarImpl.java:201)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4783)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:733)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.addNotify(IdeRootPane.java:161)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:786)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:490)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1048)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.show(IdeFrameImpl.java:127)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1734)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1681)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.WindowManagerImpl.allocateFrame(WindowManagerImpl.java:574)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.init(ToolWindowManagerImpl.java:400)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl$3.projectOpened(ToolWindowManagerImpl.java:174)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:518)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:142)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:438)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:398)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:388)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:372)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.lambda$createTopicHandler$1(MessageBusImpl.java:241)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.projectOpened(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.fireProjectOpened(ProjectManagerImpl.java:845)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$doLoadProject$9(ProjectManagerImpl.java:453)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransactionAndWait$2(TransactionGuardImpl.java:162)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:107)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:687)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:965)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:186)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:172)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:455)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:453)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:82)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:250)
        at com.intellij.platform.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$1.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:64)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:149)
        at com.intellij.platform.ProjectUiFrameAllocator.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.openExistingProject(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:234)
        at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase.openProject(RecentProjectsManagerBase.kt:281)
        at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase.reopenLastProjectsOnStart(RecentProjectsManagerBase.kt:382)
        at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter$main$4.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:533)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:107)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:116)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
        at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter.main(ApplicationLoader.kt:523)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$8$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:242)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:193)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$8.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:241)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:783)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

As a result, the IDE window opens but no dialogs pop up when selecting their items from the menu.

For completeness, the following warnings occur in both local and remote launch of the program:

```
2019-12-25 12:43:06,313 [  13224]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: VibrantInk from plugin: com.intellij.database
2019-12-25 12:43:06,314 [  13225]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: WarmNeon from plugin: com.intellij.database
```

The laptop is 64-bit, it has NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 with CUDA 10.2 installed.

Do you know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one with the issue.

Seems you can fix it by staring up idea with nosplash:

```
./idea.sh nosplash
```

https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions/issues/289#issuecomment-569134220